# Internal server error - Cannot serve directory

Tags: craft3, error-message, error, server

Randomly a couple of times a day my website throws an Internal Server Error that fixes itself within minutes. Checking the logs (have replaced my username with 'username') it looks like a server issue but the server hosting company insist it's a build problem.

```
[Fri Feb 25 00:00:03 2022] [notice] [pid 342] prefork.c(907): AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 25 00:00:03 2022] [notice] [pid 342] log.c(1561): AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Feb 25 02:07:26 2022] [error] [pid 152869] mod_autoindex.c(2324): [127.0.0.1:56052] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /storage/username/www/public_html/public/uploads/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.html,index.php,index.shtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Fri Feb 25 07:25:05 2022] [error] [pid 153017] mod_autoindex.c(2324): [127.0.0.1:52006] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /storage/username/www/public_html/public/static/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.html,index.php,index.shtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Fri Feb 25 07:25:06 2022] [error] [pid 156588] mod_autoindex.c(2324): [127.0.0.1:52024] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /storage/username/www/public_html/public/static/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.html,index.php,index.shtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Fri Feb 25 07:25:06 2022] [error] [pid 152869] mod_autoindex.c(2324): [127.0.0.1:52030] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /storage/username/www/public_html/public/static/js/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.html,index.php,index.shtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I'm stuck for ideas other than rebuilding the site, if anyone has an idea I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: What is your DirectoryIndex and Options directive look like?